# Error in Android project name in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Whenever I create a new Android project in Eclipse, it shows an error in the project name and not anywhere else. What is the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: no message at all in the `Console` window for the project?

Comment: what is the error that you're getting?

Comment: Look in the 'Problems' tab (which you might need to add to the Perspective using Windows -> View)

Comment: Try a rebuild, this helped me a lot when a Android project showed some undefined errors. Often something is wrong with the R file which is newly genenerated if you rebuild the project.

Comment: ya in the problems tab its shows that "Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: wrapper was not properly loaded first:Unknown Android Packaging Problem" pls help me to solve it

Comment: What is the error message ?

Which version of eclipse ?

Which version of android eclipse plugin ?

Did you choose a target SDK ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should clear your project by 
 Project>clear menu 
then build your project

if not solve try this
 and configure build path 
by right click on project > build path > android > restore default

I hope this is help

Answer (score 3):

Try restarting eclipse and then try to open the android project you've created. Happens to me too sometimes.