# Where should I put the "ttf" files in an Android project?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

I'm trying to use fonts in my project using Typeface. I copied the `"font.ttf"` into a folder named "fonts" inside "assets" folder. But eclipse do not allow to compile it. It shows an error on fonts folder. What should I do?

The error I get is:

```
invalid resource directory name     fonts   /NoRats/assets  line 1  Android AAPT Problem
```

Comment: Can you paste the exact error you are getting?

Comment: show the code that you are using to get access the font.ttf file.

Comment: invalid resource directory name   fonts  /NoRats/assets line 1 Android AAPT Problem

Comment: My dear you should put the logcat output instead of this kind of message, Sparkymat is asking for the logcat output.

Comment: Its not running at all. Eclipse do not allow to compile, saying that there is this error.

Comment: @dinesh707 please checked "problems" like "logcat" and delete your error . then compile it again.

Comment: Console output, not logcat output, is what they are looking for. Can you copy the whole block of output you get when compilation fails and paste it as code in your original post?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Please check [this link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/), it may be helpful to you.

---

**OR**

---

use below code.

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"fonts/LATINWD.TTF");
txt1.setTypeface(tf);
```

.ttf file is in --> assets/fonts/LATINWD.TTF

Please first clean your project then check again.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Why is this better than specifying fonts in an xml file?

Answer (score 5):

Put your Font File in Assest Folder,

and in use Bellow Code for access.

```
Typeface tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Century Gothic.ttf");


textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewone);
       textview.setTypeface(tf);
```

ttf file is in --> assets/fonts/Century Gothic.ttf

Comment: In Assest Folder also fonts folder and in fonts folder Centrury Gothic.ttf file place

Comment: The code i use is same as you presented. The fonts are added in to "Assest/fonts/font.ttf".

Answer (score 3):

@ Android studio within Please check this code may be helpful to you

app/src/main/assets/your ttf file.

@ Add this code in activity.

Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "");
txt.setTypeface = (typeface)

@ Add this code in Adapter

Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "");
txt.setTypeface = (typeface)

Comment: The code i use is same as you presented. The fonts are added in to "Assest/fonts/font.ttf".--

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to define these typefaces in an xml file?  Then you can apply it directly in the layout, instead of coding it in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you everybody for answers. But i managed to make it work by doing following

"clean your project with Project menu > clean tab then build your project

If it's still unsolved, configure build path by right click on project > build path > android > restore default

I hope this is helpful"

answer found at [Error in Android project name in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017555/error-in-project-name)

Comment: Check my answer i have written clean your project.

Answer (score 0):

As of **Android Studio 1.5.1** you can:

1. Right click on your `app` directory
2. `New` > `Folder` (this is near the bottom of the list and is easy to miss) > `Assets Folder`
3. In most cases you can leave the folder location as the default > `Finish`
4. Move your files into the newly created `assets` folder

Answer (score 0):

Since font organization and utilization has changes in Android 8 (API 26), it is now recommended to put your fonts into `/res/font/` directory and access them with:

```
(Typeface) ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.your_font_bold);
```

which will return a Typeface object you needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should put fonts inside this path

> \app\src\main\assets\fonts

*[Note : Create a new directory(Folder) inside the assests directory in the above patha i have created ]*

Then put your ttf font file inside the  fonts directory .
You can set your font like this way :

```
Typeface anyName  = Typeface.createFromAsset(Context,"fonts/yourFontFileName.ttf");

simpleTextView.setTypeface(anyName);
```