# getting exception with ITEXT at BaseFont.createFont

Tags: java, android, itext

I am trying to create font like this

```
BaseFont base = BaseFont.createFont("/Users/imac/Library/Desktop/THSARPSK.TTF",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font font = new Font(base, 18f);
```

but I have a problem with the Path locating the font .

i'm working on android platform on Mac PC, i tried with many solutions, but was unable to solve.

below is one of the solution to get the path of Font on windows

```
BaseFont.createFont("c:\\winnt\\fonts\\comic.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

i try to adapt it for Mac but it sent me an exception

```
java.io.IOException:\Users\imac\Library\Desktop\THSARPSK.TTF not found as file or resource.
```

i am trying to solve this problem for many days, please help me.

Comment: and does the file exist?

Comment: Store that file in internal storage or in sd Card, then access from there..

Comment: @CRUSADER you means store file in my tablet?

Comment: @VinsantValentine yes, store first and then read your file from there...

Comment: @CRUSADER excuse me, how to read it from my tablet?

Comment: @VinsantValentine [refer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3779985/2345913)

Comment: @CRUSADER thanks for your help, i have to try it!

Comment: @CRUSADER thanks you so much,i got it!. if i want to add font into my project such as store file in assets, How to call it to read?

Comment: @VinsantValentine [refer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6506912/2345913)

Comment: @CRUSADER i have tried this solution but BaseFont.createFont not accept Typeface. How to i can adapt Typeface or else?