# Android loading Typeface from .tff

Tags: java, android, eclipse, text, fonts

So. I'm trying to load Typeface object using the following method:

```
Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Chantelli_Antiqua.tff")
```

But for some reason that's giving me

```
02-17 17:41:11.449: W/WindowManager(984): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x0/d=0x0}
```

I have been trying to seek for an answer from posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506762/where-should-i-put-the-ttf-files-in-an-android-project). All only suggesting that I should add the file to assets folder and then clean the eclipse project. I have done that but it doesn't seem to help.

.tff file is the same as used in [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-customize-android-fonts--mobile-1601) guide so I guess there shouldn't be problems with the .tff file itself?
Do I have to somehow manually add those Typefaces to R.java or something?

Comment: Type of file should be .ttf not .tff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file format is wrong. It's not `tff` but `ttf -->True Type Font`.

I've read the link you posted maybe there's a typo because at a certain point it says:

> ...Download it and place the **TTF** file in the ./assets directory (create
>   it if it doesn't exist yet)...