# Is it possible for an Android and iOS app to display the exact same font?

Tags: android, ios, fonts

If I have a TextView from Android and gave it a custom font. And then took a UITextView/UILabel from iOS and gave it the same custom font.

Will the two Operating Systems display the fonts exactly the same?

Would I be able to take a screenshot on both platforms (making sure that the resolutions and screen sizes are the same) and be able to overlay the text on top of each other with no overlap?

Comment: you can use on custom font on both platform iOS and android Also.

Comment: Yes! you can display the exact font in both android and iOS by using custom font files.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use .ttf file of particular font for both android and ios then only it can be display similar font in both os.

Please refer below link for ios and android:-
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app

[Where should I put the "ttf" files in an Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506762/where-should-i-put-the-ttf-files-in-an-android-project)